# Cannot drop primary key or add primary key

Tags: db2, iseries, db2-midrange

This db2 query:

```
alter table mylib.mytable add primary key(field1, field2, field3)
```

returns

> [SQL0624] Table MYTABLE in MYLIB already has a primary key'.

However

```
alter table mylib.mytable drop primary key
```

returns:

> [SQL0539] Table MYTABLEin MYLIB does not have a primary or unique key'.

How can I remove the existing primary key and create the new one?

The file was created in green screen, not by executing a SQL CREATE TABLE. The database version is V7R2.

Comment: Query the catalog views to verify what constraints, if any, exist for the table.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. If you mean SYSCAT and SYSSTAT, they are not available. I tried to add SYSCAT and SYSSTAT to "Schemas to display" in Navigator but it could not find them.

Comment: SYSCAT and SYSSTAT are the schemas used in DB2 for LUW. On IBM i you probably want to use the [QSYS2 schema/library.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm)

Comment: Sorry for the late response .This should have been the answer. The link is especially valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all FKEY/PKEY/CHECK Constraints in QSYS2.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS to see and/or remove any keys built on the table.